# Access to PasswordVault fails for user account delegation

Tags: c#, uwp, passwordvault

We are porting a Windows Phone 8.1 app to UWP. In the original app we used PasswordVault (`Windows.Security.Credentials`) to store user credentials and everything just worked fine. After the porting every operation related to PasswordVault throws exception with the following message:

> The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be
>   trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured
>   to allow delegation. Failed to open store.

If I run the app on my local machine everything is ok, but on the office tablets (with a lot of additional security things like bitlocker, user domains, etc.) the error just shows up.

I also tried to create a blank app, and add/retrieve credentials to/from PasswordVault, but the same happened.

Any ideas?